# Python Django Bound Form not returning

Tags: django

I am trying to validate a form by using is_valid() method.

```
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            return (RegisterForm)
```

if there is error,  I want tot return Bounded Registerform but I am getting 'get' error. If i remove the if block it is returning 'None' type error.
my question is how do i return a bounded form.

Comment: Check the django tutorial, this is basic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            return render(request,{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
    else:
       form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,{'form':form})
```